# user.agent value for chrome

Tags: javascript, gwt, google-chrome-devtools

Quick question. What's the user.agent value for chrome browser with gwt 2.4? I'm trying to limit permutations for my chrome and it doesn't compile (value used - 'chrome'). However this compiles properly

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The permutations for both safari and chrome are same and named as "safari". 
The safari setting will work for chrome also. 
You can check "com.google.gwt.user.rebind.UserAgentPropertyGenerator".

However if you wish to limit it for chrome particulary, you can see [here](http://bear-z.com/gwt/patching-google-web-toolkit-for-compiling-chrome-permutation/)